# Name for a type constructor that is both a category and a monad?

Tags: haskell, agda, category-theory

Is there any standard name for a type constructor `F :: * -> * -> * -> *` with operations

```
return :: x -> F a a x
bind :: F a b x -> (x -> F b c y) -> F a c y
```

that is a contravariant functor in the first argument and a covariant functor in the second and third?  In particular, does this correspond to any kind construction in category theory?

The operations give rise to a

```
join :: F a b (F b c x) -> F a c x
```

operation that makes this seem like some kind of "category in the category of endofunctors", but I'm not sure how that could be formalised.

EDIT: As chi points out, this is related to the indexed monad: given an indexed monad

```
F' : (* -> *) -> (* -> *)
```

we can use the Atkey construction

```
data (:=) :: * -> * -> * -> *
    V :: x -> (x := a) a
```

and then define

```
F a b x = F' (x := b) a
```

to get the kind of monad we want.  [I've done the construction in Agda to check.](https://gist.github.com/jesyspa/e1351d13dbab66bad6bae663e7df6410)  I'd still like to know whether this more limited structure is known, though.

Comment: It looks similar to an indexed monad, but not quite the same (?)

Comment: Oh yes, good point, there is a connection there.

Comment: I'd still call it a special case of an ([Atkey-style](https://bentnib.org/paramnotions-jfp.pdf), not [McBride-style](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Kleisli.pdf)) indexed monad, it just has some additional profunctor-ness in the indices. The indexed state monad, for example, fits this pattern. (Robert Atkey introduced these in the paper I linked, hence McBride's characteristically punning name for the "at key" type `:=`.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.  (And Robert Atkey even anticipated a problem I think I'll run into with his tensor product requirement.)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, this is the notion of a Parametrised Monad introduced by Robert Atkey in his [Parametrised Notions of Computation](https://bentnib.org/paramnotions-jfp.pdf) paper.  This corresponds to the notion of a category enriched over a category of endofunctors in category theory.

For a category `C` to be [enriched over a category `V` with monoidal structure `(I, x)`](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category#InMonoidCat) means that for every objects `X`, `Y` of `C`, the Hom-object `Hom(X, Y)` is an object of `V`, and there exist morphisms that give the identity and composition, `I -> Hom(X, X)` and `Hom(Y, Z) x Hom(X, Y) -> Hom(X, Z)`.  Certain idenity and associativity conditions must hold, corresponding to the usual requirements of identity and associativity for a category.

A monad `M` on `C` can be seen as a one-object category enriched over endofunctors on `C`.  Since there is only one object `X`, there is also one Hom-object `Hom(X, X)`, which is `M`.  The return operation gives rise to an identity morphism, a natural transformation `I -> M`, and the join operation gives rise to a composition morphism, a natural transformation `M x M -> M`. The identity and associativity conditions then correspond exactly to those of a monad.

A parametrised monad `M` on `C` with parameters taken from some set `S` can be seen as a category with elements of `S` as objects, enriched over the endofunctors of `C`.  The Hom-object `Hom(X, Y)` is `M X Y` and the `return` and `join` operations described in the question again give rise to the families of morphisms required.